# Add multiple rows to a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app with a building model, each building has multiple floors. Floors belong to buildings

My question is, in my building form how could i create multiple floors by simply asking the user to input the number of floors they require

Comment: Could you update your question adding what you have tried so far?

Comment: I am on my mobile, I haven't had a chance to try.

Comment: You mean something like selecting in  building form the number of floors and once that value is entered a row is appended for each floor? And each floor row is a nested form inside building form?

Comment: Could you check your question? or please update your question more specific as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are asking to creating a dynamic nested form in Rails.

- You can do it manually with Jquery & normal Rails form. This [tutorial](https://blog.auranbuckles.com/assets/img/2017-10-28/sponsorship-levels.gif) might help

[image]

- Or You can try the [Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) gem. It surely can help